# sscanf embedded device?

Tags: c, scanf

I have a problem with sscanf in an embedded device language is C.
My code is like this:

```
unsigned char by = 0;
char txt[] = "12";
sscanf(txt , "%hhd" , &by);
printf("%d" , by);
```

When i run this code in linux its correct, but in windows (VS2010) has error :

> "Stack around the variable 'by' was corrupted".

And in my embded device has error variable 'by' changes to zero.

what should i do with this code?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what is that `%hhd` format?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but perhaps VS implements string literals as something different than 1 byte (wchar_t?).

Comment: Your linux compiler, apparently, targets C99; your Windows compiler, apparently, targets C89. The different implementations have different conversions for `sscanf()`.

Comment: `printf("%d" , by);` will not work correctly because you are giving it a 1-byte variable when it expects a 4-byte variable. Because printf doesn't have type-checking, it will blithely read 3 additional bytes that follow your 'by' variable, whatever they may be.

Comment: i have checked all of the modifiers in sscanf 
i wanna read only **one byte** from my string not more 
but when i used every modifier it will read more than one byte 

int in this embded device is 2 bytes cause of this i cant use %d

i dont know what should i do 

HELP

Comment: @pmg I thought this was a C99 issue too, but the list of changes in the beginning of the C99 document does not list this as a new feature. At the same time, I can see that %hh doesn't exist in early C90 drafts. Can anyone confirm that this was introduced in C99, or does someone know of a more reliable list of C99 changes than the one in the standard?

Comment: The list of changes shows some of the *"Major changes from the previous edition"*.

Comment: @Mehdi See my answer below. First read the number into an unsigned int, and then assign that to your unsigned char variable.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdb9w69d.aspx) on `scanf` width formating, the `"hh"` specifier isn't supported by VC++.

Use [`strtol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4z2wdyc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead if you can.

Comment: i have tested all of this modifiers but my problem exist yet

Comment: @Mehdi Then you are doing something else that corrupts the stack. Can you add a more complete code snippet to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/):

```
const char* txt = "12";
unsigned char by = (unsigned char ) atoi(txt);
```

And another thing.

```
printf("%d" , by);
```

This will not work correctly because printf is expecting a signed int and is getting an unsigned char. It might work only if your embedded system has 8-bit integers, but it will not work on a PC.

Also the reason you are getting the corrupted stack error is because sscanf interpreted %hhd to mean it should read a decimal value (I tested it on my computer), and so it overwrote the memory around the variable 'by' with 4 bytes (if you have 32-bit ints).

Comment: -1, it is standard. ISO 9899:2011 7.21.6.2. `"hh Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, X, or n conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to signed char or unsigned char."` The problem here is that Microsoft is not following the standard.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Thanks for clarifying. Well, I guess you never stop learning. I had never heard of %hhd.